# Unwanted border around 320px wide div

Tags: html, css, border

I am implementing a page with responsive design. It has a minimum width of 320px. When I shrink the screen to 320px wide, there is still a small border around it, which is part of `<body>` (I have set the background color to red).

[image]

My CSS is:

```
body {
    background-color: red;
    color: #010109;
}

#newPageTable {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 320px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #FFFFFD;
}
```

How can I get rid of this border space and make sure my `#newPageTable` fits exactly within the screen?

Comment: Have you reset the default user agent stylesheet? Try `margin:0px` on the body..?

Comment: No. I did try in the past, but it was breaking my layout...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reset the default `margin` and `padding` on `body` as below:

```
body {
    background-color: red;
    color: #010109;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Doing this should remove that space.

Answer (score 1):

By default some browsers have a margin/padding around the edge of the body.

Other elements have margin/padding by default too.

You can either add a reset to the beggining of you styles, take all margin/padding off by default:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

or just apply it to the body tag:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Some reset style sheets take care of this for you if you use one.